Defining and computing the mean of a Gaussian measure in an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space
Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $\mathscr{B}(H)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $H$. In Da Prato's book An Introduction to Infinite-Dimensional Analysis he defines the mean of a measure Gaussian measure $\mu$ as follows:

Assume that $$\int_H \|x\| \mu(dx) < \infty.$$ Then for any $h \in H$ the linear functional $F: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$F(h) = \int_H \langle x, h \rangle \mu(dx), \quad h \in H$$ is continuous since $$|F(h)| \leq \int_H \|x\|\mu(dx), \quad h \in H.$$ By the Riesz representation theorem there exists $m \in H$ such that $$\langle m, h \rangle = \int_H \langle x, h\rangle\mu(dx), \quad h \in H. \tag{1}$$ $m$ is called the mean of $\mu$. We shall write $$m = \int_H x \mu(dx) \tag{2}.$$

Later on in the text he gives the following theorem:

There exists a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(H, \mathscr{B}(H))$ with a mean $a$, covariance $Q$ and Fourier transform $$\hat{\mu}(h) = \exp\Big\{i\langle a, h\rangle - \frac12 \langle Qh, h\rangle\Big\}, \quad h \in H.$$

Given an orthonormal basis $(e_k)$ on $H$, set $x_k = \langle x, e_k \rangle$. Let $P_n$ be the projection defined by
$$P_nx = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k, \quad x \in H. \tag{3}$$
Let $(P_n)$ be the sequence of projectors defined by (3) and let $h \in H$. In proving the assertion that the mean of $\mu$ is $a$ as in the above theorem, Da Prato gives the following equalities:
$$\int_H \langle P_n x, h \rangle \mu(dx) = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_H x_k h_k \mu(dx) = \sum_{k=1}^n h_k \int_\mathbb{R} x_k N_{a_k, \lambda_k}(dx_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n h_ka_k = \langle P_n a, h \rangle \tag{4}$$
My questions are the following:

What is the need to define the mean of $\mu$ in terms of an inner product as in (1) and why not directly define it using (2)?
How do we interpret the integral in (1), or any of the integrals preceding it, if the integrand is a scalar and not an element of $H$?
In the second equality in (4) how does one go from an integral over $H$ to an integral over $\mathbb{R}$?


For your question 1, (2) is a conventional notation, unless you work on Bochner integral (Integral in vector-valued function and scalar-valued measure). Is Bochner integral is defined on your book?

@ShoboDra If we interpret the integral as a Bochner integral then is (2) a valid definition for the mean?

Yes, you can check the consistency between the definitions (1) and (2) by step-function argument. That is,  for $m' = \int_H x \mu(dx), \quad<m', h> = <m, h> \quad h \in H$.

@ShoboDra Thank you. So the use of an inner product in the definition is only to avoid using Bochner integrals? I don't recall the book mentioning Bochner integrals but I am familiar with them.

I don’t know it is the ONLY way to avoid Bochner integrals, but I think most of interesting facts related to mean or higher moments can be obtained by the definition provided by (1). If there are no Bochner integrals in your book, then you can focus on (1) with a conventional notation (2).

@ShoboDra Thanks for all the help. Do you happen to have any insight on my question 3 as well?

I posted an answer including it.

The one with inner products is called the Pettis integral.  In Hilbert space, its existence is easier to prove than the Bochner integral.

@GEdgar Is there any benefit to using Pettis integrals for defining the mean in infinite dimensions instead of Bochner integrals? Based on your comment I assume this is to make some proofs easier?

1.As I wrote in comments, we can define mean by (2) if we consider the integral in the equation as Bochner integral, and it is consistent with (1). It is expected that (2) is just a conventional notation in this book.
2.The integral must be scalar-valued if we work on the definition (1). You should always interpret integral as it is defined by (1) because (2) is not a definition as I argued above.
3.Note that $x_k$ is a function on $H$; We write $x_k = p_k(x)$ where $p_k$ is the $i$th coordinate of $x$ (That is, $p_k(x)=\langle x, e_k \rangle$). Then,
$$\int_H x_k h_k \mu(dx) = h_k \int_H p_k(x) \mu(dx) = h_k \int_{\mathbb R} x_k \mu(p_k^{-1} (dx_k))$$
In the above equation, I changed the variable $x$ in $H$ to $x_k$ in $\mathbb R$. Hence it suffices to see that
$$\mu \circ p_k^{-1} = N_{a_k, \lambda_k}$$
I interpret $N$ is a gaussian measure on $\mathbb R$, $a_k, \lambda_k$ is mean, variance of $x_k$, respectively. It is almost trivial, since
$$x \sim \mu \implies p_k(x) = x_k \sim \mu \circ p_k^{-1} $$
and the pushword measure $\mu \circ p_k^{-1}$ is a gaussian measure by the definition of it.

Thank you very much for all your help!
